# how to use driver program in jgrasp

Tags: java, driver, jgrasp

I have a program written and there is a driver program to test the code I have written and I can not figure out to get the driver to run with my program in Jgrasp? Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the source code for the driver, open it, compile if necessary, and run. If you have only a .class file, there is no simple way to run it in jGRASP.